# Number of edges to a random sample of vertices (igraph)

Tags: r, igraph

The problem I'm facing is that I want to know how many nodes are connected to a random selected set of nodes in a igraph. So I'm using a dataset which has numerous nodes. I've made a smaller example graph, which should be sufficient to explain my question.

Here is the example code:

```
library (igraph)

#### Random graph #####
set.seed(1) #reproduction
g <- erdos.renyi.game(50,1/35, directed =  F, loops = F)

#### simple random sample from graph object #####
set.seed(123) #reproduction
smpl <- sample(1:vcount(g),20)

#### assign random sample to a igraph attr ####
V(g)$randomSample <- "0"
V(g)[smpl]$randomSample <- "1"

##### plot #####
V(g)$color = "#F5E31C" #yellow
V(g)[smpl]$color="#1CA38B" #green

set.seed(123) #reproduction
plot(g,
    vertex.label.color = "Black",
    vertex.size = 15,
    layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold(g))
```

[image: image of the graph]

In the example graph I want to know which and how manny of the non-samples nodes (yellow) are <2 times connected to the sampled nodes (green). And which and how many of the non-sampled nodes (yellow) are connected >= 2 times with the sampled nodes (green).

```
#### options? ####
adjacent_vertices(g, 34, mode = "total")
#Is there a option to use a count or a loop function of some sort for this?

V(g)$degree <- degree(g,v=V(g), mode="total", loops = FALSE, normalized = FALSE)
#Does give the number of ties a node has, is there a option to change this in a way so it only gives the degree to the sampled nodes?
```

For example node 34 is connected to nodes 3, 32, 39, 44, 48. In the desired output node 48 should be dropped and the degree should be 4. Further more I would like to know if there is a way to count how manny nodes have <2 ties with the sampled nodes and how many nodes have >= 2 ties with the sampled nodes for the graph.

*Side note: my skills in R are really on novice level, so please bear with me*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let's define a function that returns neighbouring nodes and associated `randomSample` flags for nodes `v` of your graph. We make use of `igraph::neighbors` and store results in a `list` of `data.frame`s.

   ```
   # Function to return vertices and randomSample
   # information for all neighbours of v
   get.neighbours <- function(v) {
       lapply(setNames(v, as.character(v)), function(x) {
           near <- neighbors(g, x, mode = "total")
           cbind.data.frame(
               vertex = as.integer(near),
               randomSample = as.integer(V(g)[near]$randomSample))
           })
   }
   ```

   *Further explanation: `get.neighbours` takes a node sequence `v` as input, and for every node from `v` determines its neighbours using `neighbors`. For every node, we extract the neighbouring numerical node id and node attribute `randomSample` and store entries in a `data.frame`. The resulting object is a `list` of `data.frame`s,  with one `data.frame` for every node from `v`.*
2. We can now count the number of connected sample nodes (`randomSample = 1`) for every non-sample node (`randomSample = 0`). To do so, we determine all sample neighbours for all non-sample nodes `V(g)[V(g)$randomSample == 0]`.

   ```
   # Number of connected sample nodes for every non-sample node
   nConnected <- sapply(get.neighbours(V(g)[V(g)$randomSample == 0]), function(x)
       nrow(x[x$randomSample == 1, ]))
   ```

   *Further explanation: For every node with attribute `randomSample = 0` we determine its neighbours; we then loop through the `data.frame`s from the resulting `list` and count the number of rows that correspond to neighbouring nodes with attribute `randomSample = 1`. This returns a vector of the number of sample nodes for every non-sample node.*
3. Then the number of non-sample nodes that are connected < 2 times to sample nodes is simply

   ```
   # Count the number non-sample nodes that are connected
   # < 2 times to sample nodes
   sum(nConnected < 2)
   #[1] 27
   ```

   And the number of non-sample nodes that are connected >= 2 times to sample nodes

   ```
   # Count the number of non-sample nodes that are connected
   # >=2 times to sample nodes
   sum(nConnected >= 2)
   #[1] 3
   ```
4. To know *which* non-sample nodes are connected >=2 times

   ```
   names(which(nConnected >= 2))
   #[1] "7"  "28" "34"
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question for me (and the community). At the moment it is unclear to me how the given function does what it does. But I'm gonna study it, so much fun to learn from it. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome @JHJH; I've added a some further explanations. Please take a look.